# Combining distinct with another condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm migrating a Rails 3.2 app to Rails 5.1 (not before time) and I've hit a problem with a where query.

The code that works on Rails 3.2 looks like this,

```
sales = SalesActivity.select('DISTINCT batch_id').where('salesperson_id = ?', sales_id)

sales.find_each(batch_size: 2000) do |batchToProcess|
    .....
```

When I run this code under Rails 5.1, it appears to cause the following error when it attempts the for_each,

```
ArgumentError (Primary key not included in the custom select clause):
```

I want to end up with an array(?) of unique batch_ids for the given salesperson_id that I can then traverse, as was working with Rails 3.2.

For reasons I don't understand, it looks like I might need to include the whole record to traverse through (my thinking being that I need to include the Primary key)?

I'm trying to rephrase the 'where', and have tried the following,

```
sales = SalesActivity.where(salesperson_id: sales_id).select(:batch_id).distinct
```

However, the combined ActiveRecordQuery applies the DISTINCT to both the salesperson_id AND the batch_id - that's #FAIL1

Also, because I'm still using a select (to let distinct know which column I want to be 'distinct') it also still only selects the batch_id column of course, which I am trying to avoid - that's #FAIL2

How can I efficiently pull all unique batch_id records for a given salesperson_id, so I can then for_each them?

Thanks!

Comment: On postgres you can use `SalesActivity.select('DISTINCT ON(batch_id), id')`. But I don't really get the point if you are only interested in the `batch_id` column - just use `.pluck` instead of instantiating records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
SalesActivity.where(salesperson_id: sales_id).pluck('DISTINCT batch_id')
```

May need to change up the ordering of `where` and `pluck`, but *pluck* should return an array of the batch_ids

Comment: I did have to put the where first, but that now returns the array of batch_ds, thanks!  I also had to change the for_each to each, as it is now an array, and for_each method isn't available, any thoughts how I can maintain the for_each batch efficiency appreciated, but thanks again!

Comment: Pluck is going to grab all that it can.  You could try and switch that out with a `select('DISTINCT batch_id')` and go back to your for_each.  Basically so it can be an ActiveRecord object instead of an array of values

Comment: OK, just tried that, and it takes me back to square one (ArgumentError (Primary key not included in the custom select clause) as it was the same as I originally had, but with changed order, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Snips d'oh yes that's pretty much the same as your original ;) because it's a *select*, the order probably wouldn't matter.  I'm not near a computer where I can play with this, but have you tried `find_in_batches` instead of `for_each`?

Comment: Gave find_in_batches a go, and back to original problem again, but thanks again for suggestion.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what SalesActivity is doing, or what is going on in your loop

Comment: I'm afraid I'm doing yet another where to sum the items in each unique batch, which is where it gets inefficient,
batchTotal = SalesActivity.where(salesperson_id: sales_id, batch_id: batchIdToProcess).sum(:quantity)

Comment: Yeah just let the database do the heavy lifting

Comment: Sorry, are you saying I'm doing the right thing, or the wrong thing there? :-)

Comment: I need to see more, this may be beyond my momentary comprehension.  An expert might know more about the Rails ORM to determine the issue.  Really, I'm curious what the SQL is.  Put `.to_sql` after the sum and display what that is.  Curious if you need to do a group_by (but you probably don't) — what DBMS?

Comment: The DBMS is MySQL, here's an example of the sum SQL taken from the log, SELECT SUM(`sales_activities`.`quantity`) FROM `sales_activities` WHERE `sales_activities`.`salesperson_id` = 123 AND `sales_activities`.`batch_id` = 9999 - thanks for looking.

Comment: hehe, no sorry, it's working now (I can try and optimise now it's working).  You asked to see the SQL for the sum so I posted it :-)  Really appreciate your help, thanks.